# Git pull without ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh

Please tell me how it happens.
I created an Ssh key and uploaded it to my github account, after that I did a git clone and git pull.
Then, I removed the ssh key from github (it's still on my computer) and I tried to make another pull request and it works great without any password required, please explain me how it works without any public key ssh on my github account?
In addition, I opened a new folder on my computer and I tried to make git clone via ssa and it did not work.
An existing repo also works without a ssh key and the new folder can not do a clone application without a ssh key (like excepted, right?)

Thanks!

Comment: what does `git remote -v` (while inside the repo) say?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub allows anyone to clone/fork public repositories without the need for an SSH key, nor does one need to connect to a repository via SSH to clone/fork a repository. Note that a SSH key is only required to connect to an SSH server (see below).

Note the purpose of an SSH key:

> SSH keys serve as a means of identifying yourself to an SSH server using public-key cryptography and challenge-response authentication. One immediate advantage this method has over traditional password authentication is that you can be authenticated by the server without ever having to send your password over the network.

Comment: I can make clone without ssh key?
I have ssh key only for push and pull?

Comment: Only for push, and only for ssh remotes (not https).